# is it possible to run KVM on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, hyper-v, kvm

Azure Fabric runs on a customized version of Hyper-V, it appears. Is it possible to run a KVM virtualized instance on Azure (using nested virtualization)?

I have a custom VHD which is based on Debian (say). Based on this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-upload-generic, it seems that it might be possible, if the Hyper-V drivers are built into the kernel.

Has anyone run successfully run a KVM instance on Azure? If so, could you please share your experience.

Comment: I have no experience of running KVM in Azure, but as for nested virtualization, there are the Dv3 and Ev3 VM series with support for nested virtualization. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/nested-virtualization-in-azure/ for the announcement and for more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization.

Comment: Reading a bit more about nested virtualization on Azure, one of the requirements is "host and guest must both be Windows Server 2016/Windows 10 Anniversary Update or later.". So, running KVM in a nested virtualization environment doesn't seem possible, at least not at the moment.

Comment: This isn't programming-related and is off-topic. Also: StackOverflow isn't a discussion forum, so asking people to share experiences... is off topic as well.

Comment: It is possible. I test in my lab, it works for me. https://imgur.com/a/TovNV

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible, but you need select Dv3 and Ev3 series VM. Also, based on my knowledge, Windows VM is also not supported, Linux VM is supported.

You need install `kvm` and `virt-manager` firstly.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install kvm qemu-kvm libvirt-bin virtinst
apt install virt-manager 
adduser `id -un` libvirt
adduser `id -un` kvm
```

You also need config nic like below: `vi /etc/network/interfaces`

```
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.100
        network 192.168.0.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.0.255
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_fd 9
        bridge_hello 2
        bridge_maxage 12
        bridge_stp off
```

Restart nic by using `/etc/init.d/networking restart`.

Now, you could create a VM by using `virt-install --connect qemu:///system -n vm10 -r 512 --vcpus=2 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/vm10.img,size=12 -c /dev/cdrom --vnc --noautoconsole --os-type linux --os-variant debiansqueeze --accelerate --network=bridge:br0 --hvm`
.

You could check the VM's status by using `virsh -c qemu:///system list`, you will get like below:

```
root@shui:~# virsh -c qemu:///system list
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 4     vm10                           running
```

Comment: More information about this, you could check this [blog](https://www.howtoforge.com/virtualization-with-kvm-on-a-debian-squeeze-server). I test in my lab, install kvm on a Linux is possible. Of course, your VM is a V3 series VM.

Comment: Works on Debian instance on Azure. I guess this was a text-book scenario, since the Hyper-V drivers were pre-installed (you'll have to use `mkinitrd` if you are using a custom image). Make sure that `hv_vmbus` is available.


Again, the `waagent` agent was already running. You'll have to install this service if you are creating a custom image.  Was able to spin up a VM and console in.