# KVM VM inside Azure Linux VM

Tags: azure, kvm, azure-container-instances

From my understanding, I can run a Hypervisor using a Windows root OS with a Dv3 sized VM using Nested Virtualization, But when it comes to using KVM instead with Nested Virtualization I'm not finding anything. Can a KVM VM run inside Azure Linux VM?

Comment: Yes. See this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49104328/4148708

Comment: It is possible. But you need select V3 series VM.